# Passing an equal sign ('=') to a parameter in a MediaWiki template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

How can I use a '=' character in a template parameter without breaking the template parser?  I'm not a MediaWIKI developer so I haven't debugged the code or checked the logs, I'm hoping someone here has a tip for escaping characters passed to templates.

Create a template called "Test" with this content:

```
{{{1}}}
```

Like this:

```
{{ Test | R = 3/(2-(1+1)) }}
```

Will render {{{1}}} instead of the complex formula!  I've determined the '=' character is the culprit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equals signs in Wikipedia template parameters won't display properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701495/equals-signs-in-wikipedia-template-parameters-wont-display-properly)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If a MediaWiki template parameter string contains an equals sign, everything before the sign is taken to be the name of the parameter.  If it does *not* contain an equals sign, the parameter string is assigned to the next available numeric parameter.

Thus, the simplest workaround, if you actually want a numbered parameter value to contain an equals sign, is to explicitly number it, like this:

```
{{ Test | 1 = R = 3/(2-(1+1)) }}
```

This will cause `{{{1}}}` inside the template to expand to the string `R = 3/(2-(1+1))`, just as:

```
{{ Test | equation = R = 3/(2-(1+1)) }}
```

will cause `{{{equation}}}` to expand to that same string.

Comment: Note that this won't work if more positional parameters follow, because specifying a positional parameter by name won't use up its positional slot. This template call:

    {{AnyTemplate|1=first arg|second arg}}
    
will assign "second arg" to {{{1}}} and leave {{{2}}} undefined.

In some cases, escaping '=' by  providing Template:= and writing {{=}} (see answer below) may be the better way.

Comment: @straycat: That's a good point, although you *can* always do `{{AnyTemplate|1=first arg|2=second arg}}`.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a `{{=}}` template whose value is `=`. Then use that template in place of the bare equal sign in your templates, like so:

```
{{ Test | R {{=}} 3/(2-(1+1)) }}
```

Comment: No love: "R Template:= 3/(2-(1+1))"

Comment: Ah, then you should edit the `[[Template:=]]` page and save it with the single character `=`. I had thought that was a MediaWiki default but apparently it's specific to Wikipedia. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this, but what about escaping the character?

Using `&#61;` will work. If you can't be bothered to remember the code, you can create the template `Template:=` with `=` as the only contents and then include it as `{{=}}`

Comment: No, using = raw in  Template:= will work just fine. The text created by expanding the templates in an template argument is never parsed again for additional arguments.

Comment: See also the source of [Template:=](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:%3D&action=edit) on Wikipedia -- it uses a raw =; the rest is boilerplate for templates. They should know best ... :)

Comment: @straycat thanks for the correction. I was erring on the side of caution, but you are right, it seems using a raw `=` is enough

Answer (score 1):

If **Extension:Variables** is enabled, use a variable. Variable definitions preserve almost all symbols, including `=` and `|`, they only perform template expansion. So it's a reasonably safe approach when dealing with complex expressions and URLs.

```
{{ #vardefine: myequation | R = 3/(2-(1+1)) }}
{{ Test | {{ #var: myequation }} }}
```